How to calculate arc-length reparameterization of a regular curve.
I am self-studying differential geometry, so please forgive my question if it is lacking in some way. I have a regular curve $\gamma : (0,\pi) \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $$\gamma(t) = \left ( \sin (t), \cos(t) + \log \tan \frac{t}{2}\ \right )$$
I know this is regular on the interval $(0,\pi/2)$  because the derivative
$$
\gamma'(t) = \left ( \cos(t), -\sin(t) + \csc(t) \right )
$$
is non-zero on that interval. How do I find
$$
\begin{split}
\phi(t) &= \int\sqrt{ \cos^2(t)+ \left ( -\sin(t) + \csc(t) \right )^2} dt  \\
&=
\int\sqrt{ \cos^2(t)+ \sin^2(t) -2\sin(t)\csc(t)+\csc^2(t)} \, \, dt \\
&= \int \cot(t) \, dt  = \ln(|\sin(t)|)+C
\end{split} 
$$
But how am I to evaluate this for some $t$ on the interval $(0,\pi/2)$?

@Pranay I think so, but the question is on the interval $(0, \pi/2)$, so it's ok right? Is it even possible to re-parametrize the curve without doing the integral?

@YvesDaoust I fixed it, but I'm not sure expanding it will help solve the integral....

@Pranay Well I can now see that, but the question on the assignment is still asking "Find the arc-length parametrization of $\gamma$ on the interval $t \in (0, \pi/2)$", and "Use the previous question to find the signed curvature $k(s)$.

Okay. Follow @YvesDaoust’s hint and expand it. It simplifies considerably.

@YvesDaoust Sorry, I have fixed it now, you greatly simplified it and I think the solution I wrote it correct... But how am I to evaluate this for some $t$ on the interval $(0,\pi/2)$?

@YvesDaoust Many apologies, I looked online for as many resources as I could find, but I'm not sure what that means, or even if this has an answer? This post: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-definite-integral-of-cot-x-from-0-to-pi-2 claims it is undefined....

@YvesDaoust I have fixed it, I also plugged it into wolfram alpha and it says it does not converge... Is there a way to skip this step to some how reparametrize it?
